# Custom function to check if documents exists in CouchDB nodejs nano

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I've been looking for an answer on Google, and based on the results found, **I am able to check** whether a table exists or not in CouchDB, using nano module.

However, when I try to make it a custom function, it always return "undefined" no matter what. Here is the function:

```
var exists = function( id ) {

    this.head( id, function( err, body, header ) {

        if ( header[ 'status-code' ] == 200 )
            return true;
        else if ( err[ 'status-code' ] == 404 )
            return false;

        return false;

    });

}
```

Call it:

```
nano.db.create( 'databaseName', function() {

    var users = nano.use( 'databaseName' );

    console.log( exists.call( users, 'documentToCheck' ) );

});
```

What exactly was wrong here? I can't seem to figure it out correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function *exists* returns undefined, because inner anonymous function returns your needed value.

Cure for this disease is to refector your function *exists*

```
var exists = function( id , cb) {

    this.head( id, function( err, body, header ) {

        if ( header[ 'status-code' ] == 200 )
            cb(true);
        else if ( err[ 'status-code' ] == 404 )
            cb(false);

        cb(false);

    });

}
```

Usage:

```
exists.call(users, 'documentToCheck', function(check) {
    console.log(check);
});
```

Comment: I knew it has to do with callbacks :-/. Thanks a lot for pointing it out!

Comment: hi. So i've tried implementing a similar function but it returns to me an error saying "header" does not contain a property 'status-code'